# Is it possible to automatically close parentheses/brackets in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, brackets

In Xcode 3, there was an option to automatically close parentheses and brackets. Is there an option to enable this in Xcode 4? I cannot find one and have been forced to close them manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is available in Xcode 4.3, it can be found in Xcode preferences.

[image]